# Can't change radiobuttons display to none again

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i got a container with 3 radionbuttons and 2 of the radiobuttons have another radiobuttons next to them but their displays are none . When i click the radiobutton i wanna display the hidden radiobuttons and when i click another radionbutton i want it's display to be none again .

```
`function showHiddenText() 
{
  if (document.getElementById("diger").checked) {
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hidden-input");
    hiddenInput.style.display = "block";
  } else if (document.getElementById("diger").checked == false) {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
  }
}`
```

It's a simple function i write to do that but else if part is not working . When i display hidden radio buttons they dont disappear ever again.
[radionbuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCT0a.png)
[hiddenpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP5EY.png)

Answer (score 0):

`const` variables are block scoped. So, in the `else if` statement `hiddenInput` is undefined.

Move it above the statements

```js
function showHiddenText() 
{
  const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hidden-input");
  if (document.getElementById("diger").checked) {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "block";
  } else if (document.getElementById("diger").checked == false) {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

By the way, you can make it simpler by replacing the `else if` statement with `else`:

```js
function showHiddenText() 
{
  const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hidden-input");
  if (document.getElementById("diger").checked) {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Or even more:

```js
function showHiddenText() 
{
  const hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hidden-input");
  if (document.getElementById("diger").checked) {
    hiddenInput.style.display = "block";
    return true; // you can return anything here
  }
  hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
  return false; // and here (it is not necessary to return here)
}
```

Comment: I've change the code but it's still not working . I can't disappear the radiobuttons when i click the another one .

Comment: @Draugnim Because you would need to call the function when a radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your radio buttons have the same name.
Radio buttons with same name are compared to each other.
Add onclick="showHiddenText()" to inputs, then:

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="btn" id="diger" onclick="showHiddenText()">
<input type="radio" name="btn" onclick="showHiddenText()">
<input type="radio" id="hidden-input">
```

js:

```
function showHiddenText() {
  if (document.getElementById("diger").checked) {
    document.getElementById("hidden-input").style.display = 'block'
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("hidden-input").style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```